# Is there a way to add a value from a non-primitive data type using a user-input?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, user-input

so I was just working on my project about Binary Search Tree, I tried to get the code about BST from a youtube tutorial and decided to try it with a java Scanner for user-input. So my question is, Is there a way to add  a value from a non-primitive data type using a user-input?

[Main Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kShQr.png)

[BST class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsuZQ.png)

I tried adding a nextInt() method inside the insert() method from the youtube tutorial so that the user can input the numbers that they like. But the ide said that the int cannot be converted into Node(which I think is a non-primitive data type).

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If your `insert` method in `BinarySearchTree` is modified so that it can take a number as input and generate a Node from it, then your code would work. Try like this:

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1st number you want to insert");
        tree.insert(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd number you want to insert");
        tree.insert(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter 3rd number you want to insert");
        tree.insert(sc.nextInt());
    }
}

class Node {
    Node left;
    int val;
    Node right;
    Node(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
    Node root;
    public void insert(int key) {
        Node node = new Node(key);
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            return;
        }
        Node prev = null;
        Node temp = root;
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.val > key) {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp.left;
            } else if (temp.val < key) {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp.right;
            }
        }
        if (prev.val > key)
            prev.left = node;
        else
            prev.right = node;
    }
}
```